# Why gossip_payload_buffer_size increases?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, performance-testing, hyperledger

I am doing performance testing on a Hyperledger Fabric-based application. In order to increase the throughput, I changed the value of BatchTimeout of the channels. Could someone please explain why the gossip_payload_buffer_size metric is increasing up to 41 when the load is high? when the load is very low it is 0. This only happened when I changed the default value of BatchTimeout of the channel.

[https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/metrics_reference.html#:~:text=gossip_payload_buffer_size](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/metrics_reference.html#:%7E:text=gossip_payload_buffer_size)

Answer (score 2):

That value represents an internal queue of blocks from the gossip layer to the ledger layer, in the peer.

When the peer's ledger is slower in processing blocks than the rate at which blocks arrive, the queue (payload buffer) is starting to fill.

Comment: Thanks @yacovm Can you please suggest a way to improve the processing speed of peer's ledger? I am using couch DB as the state database.

Comment: don't use couchDB :D